# Add testthat to project using magrittr

Tags: r, testthat

I have an legacy project that doesn't uses namespaces. When I add testthat package it seams that it shadows some functions from magrittr package, especially `magrittr::equals`. I use roxygen to import packages, and import in  comments only magrittr function:

```
#' @import magrittr
NULL
```

But equals still point to testthat

Comment: You can make it more explicit and use `magrittr::equals()` instead. Also: Do you import or suggest `testthat` in the `DESCRIPTION`? The preferred way of doing it would be to list it under `Suggests:`

Comment: Another point, you could think about using `# @importFrom magrittr equals`, which does not solve your problem at hand but might be better if you do not expect to use all functions from magrittr